# How to design the page for model List Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have around 20 cities in my database. I need to develop a page where I can allocation some value to each city. I can update the allocation in the page.

My Data base looks like below

```
City table - > City(CityId, Name)
```

I have a table to store the allocation for cities

```
Table - > CityAllocation(CityId, Allocation)
```

I have to display a text box near all the city names.

```
CityAllocationViewModel.cs

public class CityAllocationViewModel
{
  public List<City> Cities{get;set;}
  public List<CityAllocation> CityAllocations{get;set;}
}

CityAllocation.cshtml
```

Step 1: To display all the cities I will loop through Cities list and display it.

Step 2: Need to display text boxes near each of the city -> which will load existing values from CityAllocations if anything is there. Otherwise just need to display empty

But for the first time CityAllocations list will be null. Can someone explain me how to construct text box with proper binding name so that when I save it, the values gets properly binded to action method parameter. I am using MVC 4.

My Action method looks like below

```
CityController.cs

public ActionResult SaveCityAllocation(CityAllocationViewModel cityAllocationViewModel)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest use `EditorTemplateFor` . Create a partial View for `CityAllocation` and call in main view `CityAllocationViewModel` with as `@html.EditorFor(m=>m.CityAllocations)`